# How to add an URL link below the image in a custom content?

Tags: media, uri

### Actual:

[image: Actual]

### Working content:

[image: working content]

**My question**: How do I achieve adding URL link below my custom content images (i.e under those four images I need the URL links)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about implementing from screenshot, defined as off-topic in Help Center.

Comment: i dont know how to do.so only asking.why down voting it?

Comment: See [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), especially "not about" part, and you'll know why downvotes. Tell us what have you tried etc. From the screenshot we can't even begin to guess what you tried to do and why it fails. We can't know how you constructed your content types, and so on.

Comment: thank you Molot.i wont ask again.i dont worry about down votes.i dont know how to do it.that's why i've raised the question.

Comment: Ask if you need, just make sure you meet standards. Screenshot-based questions are usually unanswerable, that's why they are forbidden. If you can ask in more answerable, and less forbidden way, feel free to edit - downvotes can be removed after edit.

Comment: I just edited this question a bit. I think I start to understand the question, though I don't want to edit it too much without changing the content of the original question ... Any dowvotes worth being reconsidered? Maybe further edits also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly: on a website page, you want to display images with some text underneath and possibly, have that text (and image) link somewhere?

Without knowing how are you collecting those images and text it may be difficult to answer it but here is what I would suggest:

1. Have a **content type** (let's call it "Highlight image") that will collect one image, text to appear underneath the image and a link you want that image and text to open.
2. Add the required images, text and links (4 in your case)
3. Create a **View > Block displa**y with filter to display content of "Highlight image" type (or whatever you named it), published. Select fields for that view and change their settings:

   - **link** - set to not display since we will use that link in image and text fields to link them to the URL from link field
   - **image** - in **Rewrite Results > Output this field as a link**: enter your link field value  (check under Patterns to see what is your link field name and enter here, as a link to be used). It will be something like [link]
   - **text** - do the same as for image field, in Rewrite Result options tell the view you want that text to appear as link
4. **Add the block to the page** where you want the images to appear.

If you don't want to use the Views, you may want to modify the custom content type, collect the link there (one for each image) and then modify the display of that content type to use the link - modify either using template functionality for that node or use Display options for that content type. I think the View implementation is more elegant and easier to maintain in the future.